# Преобразовать время в метку времени UNIX

Tags: php, дата, время

Я получаю дату и время в таком формате: `2017-8-15T12:45` 
Как ее можно преобразовать в метку времени UNIX?

Comment: Ну так секунды тоже считайте. И новый вопрос нужно задавать отдельно от старого.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Функция strtotime:

```
echo strtotime("2017-8-15T12:45");
```

Comment: У меня не сходится время, добавил в вопрос пояснение.

Comment: секунды не указаны $date = date("Y-n-j")."T".date("G:i:s");

Comment: А, моя оплошность, спасибо)

Comment: @Erm, неуказание секунд - не единственная проблема расхождений. Вы пытаетесь получить время несколько раз подряд, а между этими попытками может проходить некоторое время, которое приведёт к разночтениям. На самом деле, вам следует обращаться к системе за текущим временем только единожды и сохранять метку где-то в отдельной переменной.

Comment: @mymedia я думаю это просто проверочный пример, но и его можно написать правильно date("Y-m-d\TH:i:s") :)